# Inner join and average in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, rounding, average

I'm new to SQL thus the question. I'm trying to query the following. Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the names of all the continents (COUNTRY.Continent) and their respective average city populations (CITY.Population) rounded down to the nearest integer.
The table schemas are `City: id, name, countryside, population`

```
Country: code, name,continent, population
```

I've written the inner join, but can't seem to figure out the way to get the `avg` city population. This is my code.

```
SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT
FROM COUNTRY 
INNER JOIN ON 
COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE;
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Here is the solution.

```
Select Country.Continent, floor(Avg(city.population))
  From Country 
     Inner Join City
        On Country.Code = City.CountryCode
  Group By Country.Continent;
```

Here, We have to group by Continent so as to have a result set for continent being the key identifier and then applying AVG function to the population for the cities belonging to this continent.

Comment: Not passing the test case, but no error logs. If you have the time you can look this link up. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/average-population-of-each-continent

Comment: fixed it for you. Enjoy and submit it.

Comment: Then accept it as answer. An upvote will not do any harm either.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) over (partition by c.Code)
    ,SUM(ci.Population)/COUNT(*) over (partition by c.Code)
FROM Country c
INNER JOIN City ci on ci.CountryCode = c.CountryCode
GROUP by c.CODE
```

I have not tested this so I apologize if it needs a little tweaking.   The concept here is to group by country code since you are looking for an average of population within specific or individual country codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNTRY.CONTINENT,floor(avg(CITY.POPULATION))
from CITY,COUNTRY
where CITY.CountryCode=COUNTRY.Code
group by COUNTRY.CONTINENT;
```

This is the most basic sql query.
**Idea:** A continent has several cities and we have to find the average population of cities. We have to make group of continents and find their average cities population.

NOTE: For this question (HACKERRANK PROBLEM), ROUND() function will give out wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONTINENT ,floor(AVG(CITY.POPULATION)) 
from CITY,COUNTRY  
where COUNTRYCODE IN (Select CODE ,from COUNTRY and GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT);
```

what is wrong in my code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30829408)